# SELECT does not selects

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm tryign to creat user_login system for my website. And now i got problems with selection of user_info from database , using mysqli and prepared statements .
My problem is , that i can't get any output . But i'm using the manual at php.net .
Here is what  i have got the moment:

```
<?php
require_once 'php/includes/constants.php';

$connection = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)or die("Error");

$phone = "0661488342";
$password = "1234";

$query = " SELECT * 
            FROM userinfo
            WHERE phone = ? AND password = ?
            LIMIT 1";

$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $phone, $password);

$stmt->execute();

$res = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();

echo "Password = ".$row['password'];
```

The error :

> Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in Z:...

Can you advise me something about this ?

**Edition 1**
PHP version is 5.2.12.(sorry, i forgot this)
But the question remains the same . How can i get the user_info ?

Comment: What's your PHP version? `mysqli_stmt::get_result()` was introduced in PHP 5.3

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of PHP? 5.2 is pretty lacking in modern PHP features and its no longer supported.

Comment: My question is not about error! It is about proper way of getting array of data !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have PHP 5.3.0 and also this method requires the mysqlnd driver. Othervise you will get this error:

```
 Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()
```

Which is what appears to be happening to you.

Answer (score 0):

What is your PHP version, and mysql version?
You should learn more about MySQLi here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score -1):

You have an error in your SQL, which you can detect by checking for errors (in this case it outputs them but there are better ways to handle errors.

```
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!($res = $stmt->get_result())) {
    echo "Getting result set failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

$row = $result->fetch_row()
```

In your case `password` column name is a reserved word in MySQl (there is a `PASSWORD` function). Your SQL should backtick column names and table names:

```
$query = " SELECT * 
           FROM `userinfo`
           WHERE `phone` = ? AND `password` = ?
           LIMIT 1";
```

FINALLY, it looks like you are stroing passwords in the clear which means **you are doing it wrong**.  See [PHP The Right Way: Password Hashing](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing)

Comment: Yes, pass is not md5ed, but this is only beta, and i'm only studying .

Comment: Even MD5 is not secure for password storage, and if you're studying nothing is better than learning the right way the first time.